# Horário atual dos estados do Brasil C#

Tags: c#, .net

Estou tentando pegar a hora atual dos estados/DF Brasil com horário diferente. Encontrei o código abaixo mas não ajudou muito. Alguém sabe alguma forma de fazer sem `webservice`?

```
public static void Main()
{
    DateTime timeUtc = DateTime.UtcNow;
    var kstZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("E. South America Standard Time");
    var horaBrasilia= TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(timeUtc, kstZone);
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Hora Brasilia: {0}",horaBrasilia));
    //Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Hora Amazonas: {0}",horaAmazonas));
    //Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Hora Acre: {0}",horaAcre));
    //Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Hora Piaui: {0}",horaPiaui));
}
```

Comment: Tente explicar melhor o que deseja e qual resultado espera obter. tente dar um exemplo

Comment: quase isso: http://www.apolo11.com/tictoc/fuso_horario.php

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A extensão territorial do Brasil compreende 4 fusos horários (-2hs, -3hs, -4hs e -5hs em relação a Greenwich).
Você pode obter a hora em cada um desses fusos através do seguinte código:

```
        Console.WriteLine ("Exibir horários conforme TimeZone");
        DateTime timeUtc = DateTime.UtcNow;
        var noronha = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Brazil/DeNoronha");
        var brasilia = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Brazil/East");
        var amazonas = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Brazil/West");
        var acre = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Brazil/Acre");

        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("UTC Time: {0}",timeUtc.ToString()));
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Hora Noronha: {0}",TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(timeUtc, noronha).ToString()));
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Hora Brasilia: {0}",TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(timeUtc, brasilia).ToString()));
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Hora Amazonas: {0}",TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(timeUtc, amazonas).ToString()));
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Hora Acre: {0}",TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(timeUtc, acre).ToString()));
```

No entanto, isso não corresponde a resposta conforme cada região do país. Por exemplo, a região Norte possui parte do seu território com -5hs (Acre), -4hs (Amazonas, Rondônia e Roraima) e -3hs (Pará, Amapá e Tocantins) em relação a Greenwich. A região Centro-Oeste, com exceção de Goiás (-3hs) está enquadrada no fuso de -4hs. O restante do Brasil (Nordeste, Sudeste e Sul) possui o fuso de -3hs. A exceção é Noronha que possui -2hs em relação a Greenwich.

Deve-se atentar para o fato que, durante o horário de verão as regiões Nordeste, Sudeste e Sul possuem o mesmo fuso de Noronha (-2hs).

Comment: Tem razão, vou reformular a pergunta a resposta é o que eu procurava.

Comment: Todos com este erro: `[System.TimeZoneNotFoundException: The time zone ID 'Brazil/Acre' was not found on the local computer.]` Sabe o motivo?

Comment: Conforme documentação MSDN https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.timezoneinfo.id(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @rubStackOverflow você deve trocar o TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Brazil/West") para algo como: TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("E. South America Standard Time") //Esse aqui representa o horário de brasília